# entity framework with SP

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using VS 2008 with SP1. I want to use SP in the entity framework. The problem is that my SP returns more than 1 result set. How do I get the multiple result sets? All the online examples are showing single result. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework unfortunately does not support multiple result sets from stored procedures - not even in the .NET 4 release.

You will need to either rewrite your stored procs, or access them using standard, bare-bones ADO.NET - and ask Microsoft for support for multiple SP result sets in EF 5 !! I'll cast my vote in favor, too!

Comment: Thanks for reply. My manager always says, there is a risk with trying new technology before it gets matured.

Answer (score 1):

Related to this question:
[Entity Framework - get records in multiple tables using stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392781/entity-framework-get-records-in-multiple-tables-using-stored-procedure)

Another SO user reports success with a plugin project, EF Extensions.

As marc_s describes, the feature is not built in to EF... another reason for DBA Developers to shy away from EF, imho.